# For apple's app reviewing, Should I provde a test user account of testflight?

Tags: ios, review

I submitted my iOS app. That app includes inapp purchase. I tested the feature whether it works correctly. After that, I submitted the app.
However, I have been gotten curious that I should provide a test user account of testflight for reviewer to test inapp purchases.

Comment: No i think you should provide sandbox user credential to check in app purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we don't have to specify that unless they come back asking you.